# why the following code show the output `('jen', 'lives in', 'Dhaka')` instead of- `jen lives in Dhaka`?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
print(name, 'lives in', location)
```

Why does this show output:

```
('jen', 'lives in', 'Dhaka')
```

rather than

```
jen lives in dhaka
```

? Why are the commas & inverted commas not omitted? Why are there brackets in the output?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. Please read [mcve].

Comment: Have you studied Python3? In it, parentheses are required for `print()` as function, and so, the output should be as you expected. But, for Python2, `print` is operator, and its single argument is tuple, so it uses tuple representation. This difference between major flavors can be source of this confusion. Also, please don't name apostrophes (single quotes) as "inverted commas".

Comment: Thanks for your correction. Actually i was bit confused how to write the question as i am new to this forum.

Answer (score 1):

In python 2.7, `print` is a statement, and does not require parentheses. This means that

```
print(name, 'lives in', location)
```

is equivalent to

```
x = (name, 'lives in', location)
print x
```

`x` is a tuple. When you print a tuple, the parentheses are visible. If the tuple contains a string, the string's quote marks are visible.

If you don't want the `print` statement to print a tuple, don't give it a tuple. Leave the parentheses out.

```
>>> print name, "lives in", location
jen lives in Dhaka
```

Answer (score 1):

Beware `print` is one of the differences between Python2 and Python3. In Python3, `print` is a function, and `print(name, 'lives in', location)` would print `jen lives in dhaka`.

But in Python2, `print` is an instruction, so `print(name, 'lives in', location)` prints the tuple (because of the commas) `(name, 'lives in', location)` what ends in `('jen', 'lives in', 'Dhaka')`.

To get the expected output, you can omit parentheses:

```
print name, 'lives in', location
```

or use join to concatenate the strings

```
print(''.join(name, 'lives in', location))
```

as the content of the outer parentheses is a mere string (no comma), they become harmless in Python2

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it.